# magento create a very special configurable product - football team

Tags: magento, attributes, configurable-product

I need on Magento 1.7 to let the user choose attributes for each quantity in a configurable product.

**The Example:**

I want to order 11 football shirt for my football team.
i need to select size and write the player's name  for each shirt in the product page like the image above

[image]

If the solution need to set "11" as default quantity, there's no problem

What i need is to have attributes repeated 11 time as quantity.

Is it possible?

How to?

Comment: It will require a not insignificant amount of custom development. It might be best to look for a quick order form extension which supports configurable products.

Answer (score 1):

this can easily be done in your theme; use the file

app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml

Hook in at

```
foreach($_attributes as $_attribute):
```

and change how the item is displayed (display it several times, for example).
Afterwards, you need to modify the javascript-function below that alle products are added to cart. You can find an example how to mass-add products here:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/9797/

Ask if you need more advice.